# Need help in creating a stored procedure to iterate tables in a database, then run a SQL statement on each table

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Our application does not delete data as we retain it for a period of time, instead we have a column "deleted" (bit) in most tables of the database that store data which we mark 1 when deleted, otherwise the default is 0.

I'd like to create a stored procedure that iterates all tables in the database, checks for the existence of a column named "deleted" and if it exists, I run a check against the LastUpdatedUtc column (datetime2) and if the date is over 6 months old and deleted = 1 then we delete the row.

This application is under continuous development so tables could be added which is why I want to create a script that iterates tables instead of having to add a line for each table and remember to add them as new tables are added.

Any help in a SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure to this would be a great help.

Thank you.

EDIT (thank you Omaer) here is what I've come up with so far.  Anyone that knows a better way let me know.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTables') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpTables
GO

CREATE TABLE #tmpTables
(
ID INT,
TableName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

INSERT #tmpTables
SELECT [object_id], [name] FROM sys.all_objects WHERE type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' ORDER BY [name]

DECLARE @TN NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @PurgeDate VARCHAR(50)

SET @PurgeDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETUTCDATE())

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmpTables) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @TN = TableName FROM #tmpTables
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'deleted' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TN)) 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'LastUpdatedUtc' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@TN))  
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL = 'SELECT Count(*) As Counter FROM ' + @TN + ' WHERE [deleted] = 1 AND [LastUpdatedUtc] < ''' + @PurgeDate + '''' -- this will be the delete line when the code is final, just outputting results for now
            EXEC(@SQL)
        END      
     END
    DELETE #tmpTables WHERE TableName=@TN
END

DROP TABLE #tmpTables
```

Comment: You've described the steps you want to implement fairly clearly (iterate over all tables, check for a column, delete rows with certain values); what have you coded so far and what precise difficulty are you having?

Answer (score 1):

This is my first attempt, not tested it so there might be some typos/syntax errors but this should get you started:

```
    declare @date6MonthsBack varchar(50)
    select @date6MonthsBack = dateadd(month, -6, getdate());

    declare c cursor for
        select 'delete from ' + quotename(name) + ' where [deleted] = 1 and [LastUpdatedUtc] <= ''' + @date6MonthsBack + '''' from sys.tables
        where object_id in (select object_id from sys.columns where name = 'deleted')
        and object_id in (select object_id from sys.columns where name = 'LastUpdatedUtc')

    declare @sql varchar(max)
    open c; fetch next from c into @sql
    while (@@fetch_status = 0) begin
        print(@sql)
        --exec(@sql) --uncomment this line to do the actual deleting once you have verified the commands.
    fetch next from c into @sql; end
    close c; deallocate c
```

Comment: As for everyone who gave this question a negative vote, I just really need 50 rep so I can comment everywhere!

Comment: Thank you for some pointers, I edited my post and added what I came up with

Answer (score 0):

You could use undocummented `sp_MSforeactable` procedure instead of loop or cursor. Something like code below. I created procedure that runs your code and is executed with `sp_MSforeachtable`. The disadvantage is - the procedure is undocumented and may not be supported in next SQL Server releases

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_cleanup') IS NULL
    EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_cleanup AS SELECT 1')
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_cleanup
    @sTblName VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    -- your variables
    DECLARE @PurgeDate  VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @SQL        VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @PurgeDate      = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETUTCDATE())

    -- we can check columns existence in one condition
    IF
        EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'deleted' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@sTblName)) 
        AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'LastUpdatedUtc' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@sTblName))
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL = 'SQL CODE GOES HERE' -- this will be the delete line when the code is final, just outputting results for now
            PRINT @SQL
            --EXEC(@SQL)                    -- uncomment for execution
        END
    ELSE
    -- for debugging
        BEGIN
            PRINT @sTblName + ' has no [delete] and [LastUpdatedUtc] columns'
        END
END


EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'exec usp_cleanup ''?'''
GO
```